# How to initialize an Either to Right and specify the type of Left?

Tags: scala, either

I would like to initialize an `Either` to `Left`, but this requires specifying the type of the `Right` side (or vice versa).

If I don't, then the `Right` side is typed to `Nothing` by default, and in order to do something such as:

```
List(5, 42, 7).foldLeft(Left("empty")) {
  case (Left(_), i)  => Right(i)
  case (Right(s), i) => Right(s + i)
}
error: type mismatch;
    found   : scala.util.Right[Nothing,Int]
    required: scala.util.Left[String,Nothing]
```

I'm obviously forced to verbosely provide the type of both sides of the `Either`:

```
List(5, 42, 7).foldLeft(Left("empty"): Either[String, Int]) {
  case (Left(_), i)  => Right(i)
  case (Right(s), i) => Right(s + i)
}
```

In a similar way, I can use `Option.empty[Int]` to initialize `None` as an `Option[Int]`, would there be a way to initialize `Left("smthg")` as an `Either[String, Int]`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, `Left` comes with a [`Left#withRight`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/util/Left.html#withRight[B1%3E:B]:scala.util.Either[A,B1]) method which allows upcasting `Left[A, Nothing]` to `Either[A, B]`:

```
Left("smthg").withRight[Int]
// Either[String, Int] = Left("smthg")
Left("smthg")
// Left[String, Nothing] = Left("smthg")
```

Same goes for the `Right` side and [`withLeft`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/util/Right.html#withLeft[A1%3E:A]:scala.util.Either[A1,B]):

```
Right(42).withLeft[String]
// Either[String, Int] = Right(42)
```

---

which gives in your case:

```
List(5, 42, 7).foldLeft(Left("empty").withRight[Int]) {
  case (Left(_),  i) => Right(i)
  case (Right(s), i) => Right(s + i)
}
// Either[String, Int] = Right(54)
```

Answer (score 12):

To supplement Xavier's answer, *cats* also provide utility methods for creating `Either`, for example, we can do:

```
import cats.implicits._

val right = 7.asRight[String] // Either[String, Int]

val left: = "hello cats".asLeft[Int] // Either[String, Int]
```

It might be useful if in case our project is using scala 2.12 or below.

In case we don't need whole *cats* library, we can, of course, borrow just [extension functions for either](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/cats/syntax/either.scala#L365):

```
implicit class EitherIdOps[A](private val obj: A) extends AnyVal {

  /** Wrap a value in `Left`. */
  def asLeft[B]: Either[A, B] = Left(obj)

  /** Wrap a value in `Right`. */
  def asRight[B]: Either[B, A] = Right(obj)

}
```